# How do I append to list only after a certain value in another python list?

Tags: python, append

I have 2 lists. I only want to append to the new list after I've reached the specified value.

```
old_list = ['apple', 'pear','orange', 'banana', 'grape']
new_list = []
value  = 'orange'
```

The desired outcome is:

```
new_list = ['banana', 'grape']
```

I've tried this, but the result is not what I want:

```
for i in old_list:
    if i != value:
        new_list.append(i)
```

Hope that makes sense!

Comment: Are you familiar with *list slicing*? Given the ability to *find* the specified value, can you think of a way to slice the list in order to get the resut you want?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `list.index` method to return the index `i` where the `value` appears in the `old_list`. Then slice `old_list` from index `i+1` up to its end:

```
old_list = ['apple', 'pear','orange', 'banana', 'grape']
value  = 'orange'

i = old_list.index(value)
new_list = old_list[i+1:]
```

Comment: This will throw a ValueError if value is not in the list, a simple try... except... can handle that. Also, I don't know if it matters to OP if new_list is overwritten, but it'ds probably be better to extend new_list rather than reassign it

Comment: My answer assumes that `value` is in `old_list`, otherwise the question makes no sense. But you're right, a simple try/except or `if value in old_list` check will get around that.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use a boolean to check if 'orange' has been passed through.

Try this:

```
old_list = ['apple', 'pear','orange', 'banana', 'grape']
new_list = []
value  = 'orange'

checker = False

for i in old_list:
  if checker:
    new_list.append(i)
  if i == value:
    checker = True
```

Hope This Helped You

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to do it. Without knowing what you have tried, here is one way:

```
i = old_list.index('orange')
i = i + 1

while i < len(old_list):
    new_list.append(old_list[i])
    i = i + 1
```

Finding the index of 'orange' and then looping through the remaining values in `old_list` and appending them into `new_list`.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `itertools` module,

```
from itertools import dropwhile


def takeafter(iterator, value):
    itr = dropwhile(lambda x: x != value, iterator)
    try:
        next(itr)
    except StopIteration:
        pass
    return itr


old_list = ['apple', 'pear','orange', 'banana', 'grape']
new_list = []
value  = 'orange'

new_list.extend(takeafter(old_list, value))
```

`dropwhile` creates an iterator that starts producing values from its input once the predicate is true. As we don't want that first item, either, we use `next` to advance passed the starting value before returning the iterator.

Answer (score -2):

You could make a if statement that checks if the first list includes your "specified value", then append to the next list.

if not, it would append to the first list.

for example

```
old_list = ['apple', 'pear','orange', 'banana', 'grape']
new_list = []
value  = 'orange'

if value in old_list:
   new_list.append('banana', 'grape')

else:
   old_list.append('banana', 'grape')
```

Haniel

Comment: This is broken in multiple ways and does not appear to understand the problem statement. `old_list` should not be changed.

Comment: I just realized that and fixed my code. sorry that I read the question wrong